# C# Respository interface with select by id method using generics?

Tags: c#, generics, repository, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I am trying to come up with a generic way to pull an object by its Id in my repository. In my database, generally, all the IDs are primary keys and are of the type integer. There may be a case, down the road where that is not true, but I still want to maintain the same method for all objects.  Here is what my Interface looks like now:

```
public interface IRepository<TE>
    {
        void Add(TE entity);
        void AddOrAttach(TE entity);
        void DeleteRelatedEntries(TE entity);
        void DeleteRelatedEntries(TE entity, ObservableCollection<string> keyListOfIgnoreEntites);
        void Delete(TE entity);
        int Save();

        //this is where I am stuck
        TE GetById();

    }
```

I have seen some code out there where reflection is used to get the ID of an object then parse all objects for that speicifc object (not ideal). I have also seen somethng like this:

```
TE GetById(Expression<Func<TE, bool>> predicate);
```

I got that idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431995/generic-repository-select-by-id-in-ef4).

I am not realy familiar with expressions yet and not sure if this will work for me or not. I guess it would, becuase I could include this expression:

```
var foo = GetById(f => f.Id == 1);
```

But I suppose that isn't really GetById, but rather I could use any expression to get what I want, right?

Any thoughts would be appreicated.

Comment: Genuine question: do you know the difference between `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and `Func<T, bool>`? You absolutely need to before going down this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why is it a `Repository<TE,TC>` instead of a `Repository<T>`?

I use two methods:

```
 TE GetById(int id){`
     return _querySource.Single(x=>x.Id ==1);
 }

 IQueryable<TE> Query(Expression<Func<TE,bool>> predicate){
    return _querySource.Where(predicate);
 }
```

(I am assuming that you have an underlying `IQueryable<TE>` field and I named it `_querySource` for this example.)

Comment: TE is the entity and TC is the context.

Comment: @DDiVita, Not a single member of the interface uses that parameter.  It should be removed.  If you are using multiple DataContext or ObjectContext types, then this should be in a class `RepositoryBase<T,TContext>`, but not part of the interface.

Comment: @DDiVita - mate, I wouldn't be passing in a Context to the IRepository. The context IS the instance of the IRepository.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, I think he is using context to mean the DataContext or ObjectContext, in which case this could make sense in an abstract class (the repository is injected with the ObjectContext via the constructor), but not in the interface

Comment: I got the idea from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx

Comment: It's a poor design choice there as well.  Even in that example, the parameter is completely unnecessary in the interface (although helpful in the implementation).  Even code you find on the internet has mistakes....

Comment: I understnad that. That is why I come here ;)

Comment: @smartcaveman, what if the name of my ID is differnt for each entity? Should I create a Base entity that inherits from EntityObject to do something like this?

Comment: @DDiVita, that approach sounds like it works, although it may be easier to implement with an interface like `public interface IHasIntId{int Id{get;set;}}`

Comment: After thinking about it, what if I were to do a Model First approach and create my own POCOs? This way I have control over the IDs and Contexts.

Answer (score 2):

I generally just have:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    ...
    T Load(object id);
}
```

I'd prefer to standardize on using the same type (`int`) for all primary keys, but if that's not possible, I'd use `object` and avoid the added complexity of a second generic parameter.

Answer (score -1):

since TE is a generic class you can't do that .

you have to limit this TE generic to implement an interface that has property called [Id]

```
interface MainInterface
{
    Int ID{get;}
}

and in Reporsitory  :
public interface IRepository<TE, TC>  : where TE is MainInterface
    {
        void Add(TE entity);
        void AddOrAttach(TE entity);
        void DeleteRelatedEntries(TE entity);
        void DeleteRelatedEntries(TE entity, ObservableCollection<string> keyListOfIgnoreEntites);
        void Delete(TE entity);
        int Save();

        //this is where I am stuck
        TE GetById();

    }
```